# To find the longest sub string in a given string s using python

Tags: python

```
s='sqrileksarrawixamwabj'
pos = 0
maxLen = 0
startPos = 0
endPos = 0


def last_pos(pos):
    if pos < (len(s) - 1):
        if s[pos + 1] >= s[pos]:
            pos += 1
            if pos == len(s)-1:
                return len(s)
            else:
                return last_pos(pos)
        return pos


for i in range(len(s)):
    if last_pos(i) != None:
        diff = last_pos(i) - i + 1
    if diff > maxLen:
        maxLen = diff
        startPos = i
        endPos = startPos + diff - 1

print "Longest substring in alphabetical order is:"+ s[startPos:endPos+1]
```

---

Now the output comes to be 'abj', but there are other sub-strings like 'eks' and 'amw'. What I want is that the output should be 'eks' which comes first as a sub-string in s and not 'abj' which is the last occurring sub-string. What modifications should be done in the above code so I get the desired output?

Comment: The longest substring of a string, is the string itself. Are you looking for the longest _increasing_ substring?

Comment: Actually i want the longest sub-string in the aphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in:

```
def last_pos(pos):
    if pos < (len(s) - 1):
        if s[pos + 1] >= s[pos]:
            pos += 1
            if pos == len(s)-1:
                return len(s) ## <<---- right here
            else:
                return last_pos(pos)
        return pos
```

when you reach the end of the string you should return `len(s)-1` and not `len(s)`